# Lua: Why changing value on one variable changes value on an other one too?

Tags: variables, lua, registering

I think that running this code you will get excactly what I mean. I want to register 5 names to a register(*people*). I loop 5 times and in each loop I have a variable *newPerson* which is supposed to save all information about a person and then be added to the *people* register. In this example only the names of the people are being registered for simplicity.
The problem is that in the end all people turn to have the same name: "Petra". I playied a bit with this but can't get a reasonable reason for this behaviour. Help appreciated!

```
local people={}
local person={
    name="Johan",
    lastName="Seferidis",
    class="B"
}
local names={"Markus", "Eva", "Nikol", "Adam", "Petra"} --people to register


for i=1, 5 do --register 5 people
    local newPerson=person
    local name=names[i]
    for field=1, 3 do --for each field(name, lastname, class)
        if field==1 then newPerson["name"]=name end --register name
    end
    people[i]=newPerson
end

print("First person name: " ..people[1]["name"])
print("Second person name: "..people[2]["name"])
print("Third person name: " ..people[3]["name"])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The big thing at hand here is that Lua the variables "containing" a table in fact only contain a reference to a table. Copying variables containing tables does only copy *the reference* to that table, and thus represent the same table as in this example:

```
a={"x","y","z"}
b=a
b[2]="Q"
print(a[2]) -- returns Q and not y. Why is easily seen by doing:
print(a,b) -- returns table: 0xXXXXXX 0xXXXXXX indicating it's the same table
```

If you really want a copy of the table, you'll need to resort to something like http://lua-users.org/wiki/CopyTable

Comment: Thanks! That explained a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
local people={}
local names={"Markus", "Eva", "Nikol", "Adam", "Petra"} --people to register

for i=1, 5 do
    people[i]={
        name=names[i],
        lastName="Seferidis",
        class="B"
        }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use `person` as a [prototype object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming). Here are some changes to the code that adds a `new` function to facilitate object prototyping.

```
object = {}
function object:new(o)
    -- use the table provided, or create a new table
    o = o or {}
    -- use this object as a prototype
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end

local people={}
local person=object:new({name="Johan",lastName="Seferidis",class="B"})

local names={"Markus", "Eva", "Nikol", "Adam", "Petra"} --people to register

for i=1, 5 do --register 5 people
    local newPerson=person:new({["name"]=names[i]})
    people[i]=newPerson
end

print("First person name: " ..people[1].name.." "..people[1].lastName.." "..people[1].class)
-->First person name: Markus Seferidis B

print("Second person name: "..people[2].name.." "..people[2].lastName.." "..people[2].class)
-->Second person name: Eva Seferidis B

print("Third person name: " ..people[3].name.." "..people[3].lastName.." "..people[3].class)
-->Third person name: Nikol Seferidis B
```